# maximum recursion depth exceeded google colab

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

Trying to run some python code on Google colab. I have some preprocessed data that I need to read in:

```
train, test, unused_feat, target_features, features, cat_idxs, cat_dims  = pickle.load(open('/content/drive/My Drive/xxx/data/train_test.pkl', 'rb'))
```

Then if I call train I get the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    697                 type_pprinters=self.type_printers,
    698                 deferred_pprinters=self.deferred_printers)
--> 699             printer.pretty(obj)
    700             printer.flush()
    701             return stream.getvalue()

8 frames
pandas/_libs/properties.pyx in pandas._libs.properties.AxisProperty.__get__()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5268             or name in self._accessors
   5269         ):
-> 5270             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5271         else:
   5272             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_data'
```

and when I call

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RecursionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-5e6a15ce28a5> in <module>()
----> 1 train.shape

321 frames
pandas/_libs/properties.pyx in pandas._libs.properties.AxisProperty.__get__()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5268             or name in self._accessors
   5269         ):
-> 5270             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5271         else:
   5272             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

When I work on my own jupyter notebook I have no problem with this. I wonder what went wrong. Also train contains roughly 250000 rows.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could change the recursion limit if that is your constraint, however, you might be in an endless loop.

This post tells you how to increase your recursion limit.
[What is the maximum recursion depth in Python, and how to increase it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323001/what-is-the-maximum-recursion-depth-in-python-and-how-to-increase-it)

However, I am not sure about the other error you got. Hope it helps a bit.

Comment: I ended up solving it by reducing the memory usage of my dataframe

Comment: Sweet, great to know! Good luck.